# Php reading from other files?

Tags: php, html

A page where you put in a reference number and that number is check from another file (which has all the reference numbers.) If the number exists it will give you a password(code).

The password is in another file which changes every hour.

So for example I go to a page then I type in 1920371 it will give me a password because 1920371 exists in another file (.txt?) And if I do it again after an hour the password will be different. I'm not sure if I will need php. I don't really have experience with php so please explain in details.

Thank you.

Edit: I would like to know how to do it and what I should do to make it work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @KittMedia how can I do it?? What should I do

Comment: Please keep in mind that SO is not a platform where we create code for you. Before asking you already should have tried something by yourself.

Comment: @KittMedia oh alright. Well any advice that will guide me would be great.

Comment: Have you tried googling: php form tutorial?

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Idea to make it really simple. I assume the file with the Password is generated by some kind of software. Can't you just generate the PHP File itself. Your use case is not completely clear, but if it is just that the user has one single code matching to the password something like this might be enough:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['code']) && $_GET['code'] == "1920371" ) {
    print("The password is: PASSWORD");
}
```

If there are several codes you  could use an array for the codes. If this array should come from a .txt with each line a code you can read the file as array by this function http://php.net/manual/de/function.file.php

Hope this helps as starter to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you use database for this. But I think this is the best & fast way to save & check password to/from a file.

**Save password to a file**

```
<?php 
$user_no = "1920371";
$file = "/path/to/the/file/".$user_no.'.txt';
$new_password = mt_rand(); /* Generating Random Number */
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $new_password);
?>
```

**Checking for password**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['code']) && $_GET['code'] > 0 ) {
  $file = "/path/to/the/file/".$_GET['code'].'.txt';
  if(file_exits($file)){
    $password = file_get_contents($file);
    echo "Password is: ".$password;
    die;
  }
  else {
    die("Invalid code.");
  }
}
?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.